# Install Yii2 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, yii2

I'm trying to install Yii2 on wordpress following this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/213/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-yet-another-approach/

But I'm stuck on this step: Create a Yii application (using yiic) under WP root, on a folder named yii.

I'm a beginner and I'm unable to understand what should I do.First I can't find yiic and I don't know how to install it! second How can I install yii using yiic? and what is the directory for WP root?

Comment: The Wiki entry you linked is for Yii 1.1 (as specified in the headline). You tagged this question as Yii 2, which of the two are you using? Assuming Yii 2 I very much doubt that the Wiki explanation would work because Yii 2 and Yii 1.1 are very, very different from each other.

Comment: But I couldn't find another tutorial for Yii2. I just need to publish my app and I'm unable to figure out how to do this :(

Comment: I understand. There is, as far as I can tell from a quick search, one Yii 2 related WordPress [Extension](https://github.com/monitorbacklinks/yii2-wordpress) available. However, as your question does not say what exactly you are trying to achieve I do not know whether it would work for you.

Comment: I just need to publish my app but I haven't done this before so I'm lost. We are using  HostGator as our server (packard.websitewelcome.com) and i need to publish my app through it. I have access to the CPanel File manager and shell but I don't know how to install my Yii2 app there.

Comment: The original question (and the Wiki post you linked) are all about integrating Yii and WordPress with each other. It has effectively nothing to do with actual deployment. Now you are saying you have a deployment issue? What is it?

Comment: I have already posted 2 questions but I found no answer. Here are the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366026/publish-my-yii-application-on-an-online-server

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414260/publish-yii2-application-on-packard-websitewelcome-com-server

Maybe my problem is that I'm asking the question the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Yii is a PHP framework, it is not a complete solution or ready CMS.
Yii (on installing) generates basic startup folders and files to get started with a new project.

To learn how to use yiic to generate basic application stucture you can watch these videos:

Installing Yii on Windows/Ubuntu:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rra_UKJRagA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k37OEf2wpHk

Installing Yii2 on Windows/Ubuntu:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiaP4V9B2WM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1xtFbO9jgQ

You should install and develop your Yii application on your localhost (Local webserver) and then upload it to your public webserver. This way is recommended.

Wordpress is a complete CMS - ready to use.

WP root is the folder where wordpress is installed. If you installed your wordpress website to your webhosting's public_html/htdocs/www folder then this folder is the root folder of your Wordpress powered website, if you installed wordpress for example in website.com/blog folder then the 'blog' folder is the WP root.

WP root is the folder where you can see in it wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, wp-config, index.php folders and files.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6xWZoCFmOw

If you want to use Yii with a Wordpress powered website I advice you to use this extention:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-wordpress/